# Serializar para objetos diferentes em C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, recursão, serialização

Como tenho de criar a minha classe em C# para conseguir serializar este json que vem num request para a minha API?

```
[{
    "name": "campo_normal_1",
    "value": "valor do campo 1 normal"
},
{
    "name": "campo_lista_1",
    "value": 
    [
        {
            "name": "campo_1_da_lista",
            "value": "valor do campo 1 da lista"
        },{
            "name": "campo_2_da_lista",
            "value": "valor do campo 2 da lista"
        },{
            "name": "campo_3_da_lista",
            "value": 
                    [{
                        "name": "campo_1_da_lista",
                        "value": "valor do campo 1 da lista"
                    },{
                        "name": "campo_2_da_lista",
                        "value": "valor do campo 2 da lista"
                    }]
        }]
}]
```

Neste momento eu tenho a classe desta forma:

```
public class FieldRequest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
}
```

No controller eu tento serializar o campo `value` para uma lista de `FieldRequest`, mas será que existe uma forma de conseguir receber os campos todos serializados corretamente? Eu preciso algo parecido com um *overload* em que o meu parâmetro `value` seja uma string ou uma lista de `FieldRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível usar "um de dois tipos" em C#, como é possível no [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Mas, como demonstra [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840745/12114971), você pode usar o tipo [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) e executar lógicas para condições de tipo. Por exemplo:

```
public class FieldRequest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public dynamic value { get; set; }
}
```

Então, você poderá condicionar o tipo da propriedade utilizando [is](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

```
FieldRequest fieldRequest = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FieldRequest>(json);

if (fieldRequest.value is FieldRequest) {
  // lógica para quando for um FieldRequest
} else if (fieldRequest.value is string) {
  // lógica para quando for uma string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Talvez algo nesse sentido aqui:

// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);

public class MyArray    {
public string name;
public object value;
}

```
public class Root    {
    public List<MyArray> MyArray;
```